# What permissions do I need to give a SQL Server user that will be able to Query, Update and Delete

Tags: sql-server

I created one, but for some reason, I can't either log into it from  ssms, either from my computer or another one on the same network.
Will appreciate some help!

Comment: Please post any error messages you are receiving or we don't know where to start with your issue.

Comment: I think having "public" role will allow user to connect.

Answer (score 0):

If the user you added is a SQL Server User, make sure that the Server instance has been configured to allow SQL Server Authentication. Depending on the Instance installation, it might be set to Windows Authentication Mode, in which case it'll only accept Windows Auth. SQL Users with username and password won't be able to log in.

[image: Enable SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode]